# What is the exact file location due to which my Brother printer is causing consistent issues?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, brother

I brought a Brother printer one year ago and I am consistently facing an issue. The issue is that the printer works fine sometimes and does not print sometimes. But note that the **test page printing always works**.

The problem is only with the pages I want to print other than the test page.

The operating system is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
The printer is [Brother HL-L2321D](https://www.brother.in/en/products/all-printers/printers/hl-l2321d).

This printer works well sometimes when I disconnect it, then remove it, and restart the system. Sometimes it stops printing suddenly after printing some pages. Sometimes it will not print but the status shows the printing completed.

Some times printer works after updating (`sudo apt-get update`) and upgrading (`sudo apt-get upgrade`). Sometimes printer stops printing after the same updating and upgrading.

You may get more information from the following details in the test page

```
Media Limits: 0.11 x 0.11 to 8.15 x 11.47 inches 
Job ID: HL-L2320D-series-337 
Driver: br12320d.ppd 
Driver Version: 6 
Description: Brother HL-L2320D series Printer 
Location: .....................
Make and Model: Brother HL-L2320D series, using brlaser v6
Printer: HL-L2320D-series 
Created at: Wed Sep 22 13:47:52 2021 Printed at: Wed Sep 22 13:47:52 2021
```

Now, I want to know the **exact file location** due to which the issue is arising consistently?

Comment: Have you installed the latest drivers for the printer to see if this would resolve the issue? [Looks like there was an update on August 19th, of this year](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?&c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=hll2320d_us_as&os=128&type3=625&dlid=dlf006893_000) 

Comment: @matigo The drivers are installing automatically, I will check the link once.

Comment: This is a long shot. Please give what you get from `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7`. Lines beginning "Couldn't" are not needed.

Comment: @brian_p       `bInterfaceClass         7 Printer` .....
      `bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer` .......
      `bInterfaceProtocol      2 Bidirectional` ........
      `iInterface              0`

Comment: @brian_p `can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable` is only the line that didn't start with "couldn't" other than the one i pasted above.

Comment: @hanugm Thanks, but no go. You do not have an IPP-over-USB device.

Answer (score 0):

> Driver: br12320d.ppd
> Driver Version: 6

You are using a free driver from the printer-driver-brlaser package. The non-free Brother printer drivers should not be needed. You want to pin down the cause of your issues. You can start by testing the printing system filters.

Execute `sudo cupsfilter -p /etc/cups/ppd/PPD -m printer/foo -e ANY_FILE > out.dat`

ANY_FILE is any text, PostScript or PDF file you can lay your hands on. The command can be run as many times as you like with a variety of files. You are looking for all the filters to complete without error.

PPD is the printer's ppd file name. I do not know what it is. You have to replace PPD with what you have.

For a log add `2>log` to the end of the command.

If `log` shows all filters running successfully, the USB connection may be tested with `cat out.dat > /dev/usb/lp0`. Check that `/dev/usb/lp0` exists. The file is sent directly to the printer without filtering.

Comment: `sudo cupsfilter -p /etc/cups/ppd/br12320d.ppd -m printer/foo -e output.pdf > out.dat 2>log` is causing 
`Segmentation fault`

and `log` contains `cupsfilter: Unable to open PPD file: Unable to open PPD file on line 0.` and `out.dat` is empty

Comment: Entirely my fault! `/etc/cups/ppd/br12320d.ppd` is wrong. Get the correct ppd file name from `/etc/cups/ppd/`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Did you access the log?

Comment: The link says: "The file you requested has been deleted"

Comment: Please check now [here](https://file.io/yYuKVJYWrWKW)

Comment: Three filters used: pdftopdf, gstoraster and rastertobrlaser. All three exited without error. The printing system looks good to me. It could be the USB connection. Hub? Cable length? Change connection?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the three you told. It is a wired USB connection.

Comment: By "Change connection" I meant change USB connection. I have added to my answer. Your issue is either with the USB connection or the printer itself. The filtering appears faultless.